# LIGHTTPD PHPMYADMIN How can I configure PhpMyAdmin to only work on a specific Subdomain

Tags: lighttpd, phpmyadmin

So I have a small server with Lighttpd and I have installed PhpMyAdmin on it.

This is the default configuration. The Computer is accessible from the Internet on Port 80.

How can I make phpMyAdmin to listen on another port other then 80 ?

Or how can I make it to listen only on a specific subdomain ?

```
# Alias for phpMyAdmin directory
alias.url += (
        "/phpmyadmin" => "/usr/share/phpmyadmin",
)

# Disallow access to libraries
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/phpmyadmin/templates" {
    url.access-deny = ( "" )
}
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/phpmyadmin/libraries" {
    url.access-deny = ( "" )
}
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/phpmyadmin/setup/lib" {
    url.access-deny = ( "" )
}

# Limit access to setup script
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/phpmyadmin/setup" {
        auth.backend = "htpasswd"
        auth.backend.htpasswd.userfile = "/etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup"
        auth.require = (
                "/" => (
                        "method" => "basic",
                        "realm" => "phpMyAdmin Setup",
                        "require" => "valid-user"
                )
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After phpmyadmin is installed in your linux server
(based on linux server flavors,such as CentOS, Debian, etc.),
use online editor to open your lighttpd.conf file and
add url.rewrite rules as shown below:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "dev\.example\.net$" {
   server.document-root = "/home/webroot"

   url.rewrite = (
       "^/(.*)\.(.+)$" => "$0",
       "^/(phpMyAdmin)/?(.*)" => "$0",
       "^/(.+)/?$" => "/index.php/$1"
   )

   url.access-deny = ( "~", "xmlrpc.php")
   server.error-handler-404 = "/index.php"
   dir-listing.activate       = "disable"
}
```

Then cd to /home/webroot directory (or any web
directory where the web root level directory will be
used for DOM (Document Objective Model) to serve web
files such as html, php, etc. Then add a symbolic link to phpmyadmin:

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin phpMyAdmin
```

Then, verify the symbolic link by typing:

```
ls -lat
```

which will display

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan 20 14:27 phpMyAdmin -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Restart lighttpd, then open `http://dev.example.net/phpMyAdmin` in your web browser (or lynx)

NOTES:
Lighttpd url.rewrite rules may vary, depending on the
type of website (such as wordpress, Laravel framework,
etc.).
This rewrite line

```
"^/(phpMyAdmin)/?(.*)" => "$0",
```

is important.

This dev.example.net domain name is used for reference. Replace dev.example.net with your domain name.